# Bottom Navigation with only 2 destinations

Tags: navigation, android, material-design, google-materials-design, bottom-navigation

According to the Material Design Guidelines the usage for Bottom Navigation recommends three to five destinations (https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/#usage)

Was just wondering what best practice dictates for designing something with just 2 destinations. For my purposes it would be a page of Images, and then a Survey filled out

Cheers

Edit: I guess a tab layout could work, but is there really a difference between using a 2 destination tab versus a 2 destination bottom nav?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Material Design docs some more, it seems that Tabs would be the option here since tabs are for grouping similar related content where as bottom navigation is primarily for navigation between distinct pages.

Comment: Exactly this. The bottom navigation should be used to give users quick access to the main views of your application especially if the user is likely to be switching between them frequently. Tabs are more appropriate for creating separate views in a page.